# Can't find any xmas deliveries after connecting to online

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

Can't find any xmas deliveries after connecting to online server.

Just normal shipments; I want to get that Raven skin but the reqs. are apparently xmas gifts totalling 4.5k km

Comment: I have never connected to World of Trucks and I still have xmas deliveries...

Comment: @badp Well apparently you need to connect to WoT to get the Raven skin. Which requires you to drive 4.5k km worth of xmas deliveries. I was able to access X-mas deliveries offline but the moment I connect online, bam, all xmas delivs gone

Comment: What level are you?

Comment: Level 3. Already did a few xmas deliverires before, but after connecting to WoT they don't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was I was trying to search through the Freight Market, as there are little to no Xmas cargo jobs.

Quick jobs yielded plenty of X-mas jobs, simply by organizing the list by weight, and since X-mas jobs all are > 22 tons,  you will easily find an xmas job around 250 - 350 km. Ended up finding this answer from the ETS2 Forums.